Identifying replacement for micro-switch, 8.5X8.5mm, locking, vertical, button, dip solder, 4 pins,
I am having difficulties to identify a spare switch and a supplier. The defective part is on an old Multiblitz Varilux 500 studio flash. The german company Multiblitz went out of business in 2016 and no support is available. The switch has 4 pins, with spacing between rows 5mm and 6.5mm respectively. The switch is activated by a vertical red actuator of square section 3X3 mm, extending 22 mm over the PCB when the circuit is open and 21 mm when the circuit is closed. A removable button, such as gray ones visible on the switches on the left protrudes out of the enclosure and works as a spacer between the finger and the red actuator of the switch itself.
